# Rotativa action return empty page

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, rotativa

I have an Action `GetCoupons(int studentId)` in `CouponsController` that return a View with coupons with the selected student. Here is my code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetCoupons(int studentId)
{
    var coupons = _context.Coupons
       .Where(c => c.StudentId == studentId)
       .Include(s => s.Student)
       .ToList();

    return View("Print", coupons);
}
```

The View Print.cshtml is as follow:

```
@modelIEnumerable<admin.Models.Coupons>
    @foreach (var coupon in Model)
    {
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="list-group">
                        <div class="list-group-item">
                            <i class="fa fa-2x fa-building-o pull-left"></i>
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">@coupon.Student.Name</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="list-group-item">
                            <label>Classe De:</label>
                            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">@coupon.Student.ClasseId</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="list-group-item">
                            <label>No De Coupon</label>
                            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">@coupon.CouponNumber</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="list-group-item">
                            <label>Code De Validation</label>
                            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">@coupon.ValidationCode</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="list-group-item">
                            <label>Cours De</label>
                            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="list-group-item">
                            <label>Annee en cours</label>
                            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">@DateTime.Now.Year</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="list-group-item">
                            <label>Signature</label>
                            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"></h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    }
<div class="row ">
    <a href="@Url.Action("PrintToPdf","Coupons")" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-print"></i> Imprimer</a>
</div>
```

When I click on the link to print the page in PDF via the `PrintToPdf` Action on `CouponsController`, it returns a blank page. `PrintToPdf` Action looks like this:

```
public ActionResult PrintToPdf()
{
    return new ActionAsPdf("GetCoupons");
}
```

I don't know where I am doing wrong. I have been stuck on this for a week now

Comment: Aren't you supposed to pass a `studentId` to the action method ?

Comment: I thought about that but i don't know how it works with rotativa

Answer (score 1):

You should change your `PrintToPdf` method to take the `studentId` too, and to pass it:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult PrintToPdf(int studentId)
{
    return new ActionAsPdf("GetCoupons", studentId);
}
```